# How to make daemon starts automatically? Ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, daemon

I have `nginx` and `postgresql` daemons installed. How can make them start automatically every time server is started?

I think to add

```
sudo service nginx start
sudo service postgresql start
```

to `~/.profile` but not sure if it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First list the service using `chkconfig` command

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -i postgresql
postgresql-8.4  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:off   6:off
```

Suppose if you want to run `postgresql` automatically every time server is started

Then Try this command

> [root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --level 5 postgresql-8.4 on

Here `--level` means in which runlevel you want to start(on) the service in my case it's runlevel 5

Do the same for other service also

After doing this servcie will automatically start when system boots.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
cd /etc/init
vim nginx*.conf
```

See `man`s :

```
init (5)             - Upstart init daemon job configuration
init (7)             - Upstart process management daemon
init (8)             - Upstart process management daemon
```

I mean :

```
man 5 init; man 7 init; man 8 init
```

found with :

```
man -k init | grep -o '^init (\w)'
init (5)
init (7)
init (8)
```